VectorKit crash on MapView
I'm seeing the following crash occurring on the below view:
Thread 6 name:
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d700c464 __terminate_with_payload + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d702acac abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 136 (terminate_with_reason.c:106)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d702ac24 abort_with_reason + 32 (terminate_with_reason.c:116)
3   VectorKit                       0x00000001ab152a3c ggl::MetalResourceManager::newBuffer(ggl::Buffer const*) + 328 (MetalResourceManager.mm:940)
4   VectorKit                       0x00000001ab14fc20 ggl::MetalResourceAccessor::endAccess(unsigned char*, ggl::BufferData const*, gm::Range<unsigned long>, ggl::BufferAccess, ggl::BufferSync) + 104 (MetalResourceAccessor.mm:124)
5   VectorKit                       0x00000001ab14fb60 ggl::ResourceAccessor::_endAccess(unsigned char*, ggl::ResourceAccessor*, ggl::BufferData const*, gm::Range<unsigned long>, ggl::BufferAccess, ggl::BufferSync) + 136 (ResourceAccessor.cpp:89)
6   VectorKit                       0x00000001ab2b21d8 md::DaVinciGroundTileData::_buildTileMeshes(std::__1::shared_ptr<geo::codec::VectorTile> const&, ggl::ResourceAccessor*, std::__1::shared_ptr<gss::StylesheetManager<gss::PropertyID>> const&, std::_... + 8508 (DaVinciGroundTileData.mm:0)
7   VectorKit                       0x00000001ab412d54 std::__1::__function::__func<md::DaVinciGroundTileData::DaVinciGroundTileData(gdc::LayerDataRequestKey const&, std::__1::vector<gdc::Resource::LoadMetadata, std::__1::allocator<gdc::Resource::LoadM... + 1168 (function.h:364)
8   VectorKit                       0x00000001ab273b20 ggl::MetalLoader::performWithAccessor(std::__1::function<void (ggl::ResourceAccessor*)> const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<ggl::RenderTransaction> const&) + 72 (MetalLoader.mm:30)
9   VectorKit                       0x00000001ab243c10 md::DaVinciGroundTileData::DaVinciGroundTileData(gdc::LayerDataRequestKey const&, std::__1::vector<gdc::Resource::LoadMetadata, std::__1::allocator<gdc::Resource::LoadMetadata>>&&, std::__1::shared... + 1764 (DaVinciGroundTileData.mm:194)
10  VectorKit                       0x00000001ab242ed4 md::DaVinciGroundLayerDataSource::createLayerData(gdc::LayerDataRequestKey const&, geo::linear_map<unsigned short, std::__1::unordered_map<gdc::ResourceKey, std::__1::shared_ptr<gdc::Resource>, gdc... + 252 (DaVinciGroundLayerDataSource.mm:62)
11  VectorKit                       0x00000001ab281f48 gdc::LayerDataSource::updateLayerData(unsigned long, gdc::LayerDataRequestKey const&, geo::linear_map<unsigned short, std::__1::unordered_map<gdc::ResourceKey, std::__1::shared_ptr<gdc::Resource>, ... + 140 (LayerDataSource.cpp:693)
12  VectorKit                       0x00000001ab281d9c std::__1::__function::__func<gdc::LayerDataSource::processLayerDataRequests(gdc::ResourceManager*, geo::TaskGroup*, long long)::$_5, std::__1::allocator<gdc::LayerDataSource::processLayerDataReques... + 164 (function.h:364)
13  VectorKit                       0x00000001ab281ca0 invocation function for block in geo::TaskQueue::queueAsyncTask(std::__1::shared_ptr<geo::Task>, dispatch_group_s*) + 108 (TaskQueue.hpp:397)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195dec13c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195deddd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:576)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195df12d8 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 600 (queue.c:321)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195df0988 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 732 (queue.c:845)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195dff894 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 392 (queue.c:7136)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000195e0009c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 156 (queue.c:7204)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ead9f8f8 _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2709)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ead9c0cc start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

View Code:
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct ListingMapView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition
    @State private var selectedListingId: Int?
    @State private var showListingPreview = false
    @Binding var isChildView: Bool
    @State private var navigateToDetail = false

    init(isChildView: Binding<Bool>) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: RestaurantService.shared.restaurants.first?.coordinates ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 34.0549, longitude: -118.2426),
            latitudinalMeters: 50000,
            longitudinalMeters: 50000
        )
        self._cameraPosition = State(wrappedValue: .region(coordinateRegion))
        self._isChildView = isChildView
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Map(position: $cameraPosition, selection: $selectedListingId) {
                    ForEach(RestaurantService.shared.restaurants, id: \.self) { listing in
                        Marker("", coordinate: listing.coordinates)
                            .tag(listing.id)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedListingId) { oldValue, newValue in
                    if newValue != nil {
                        showListingPreview = true
                    } else {
                        showListingPreview = false
                    }
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()

                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    if showListingPreview, let listing = selectedListingId {
                        MapListingView(listingId: .constant(listing))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                navigateToDetail = true
                            }
                            .transition(.slide)
                            .animation(.default, value: selectedListingId)
                    }
                }
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Button(action: { dismiss() }) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .background(
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.white)
                                .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                                .shadow(radius: 4)
                        )
                        .padding(.top, 40)
                        .padding(.leading, 32)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                isChildView = true
            }
            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
            .background(
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: selectedListingId.map { listing in
                        ListingDetailView(
                            listingId: listing,
                            isChildView: .constant(true)
                        )
                        .environmentObject(RestaurantService.shared)
                        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                        .onDisappear {
                            clearSelectedListing()
                        }
                    },
                    isActive: $navigateToDetail
                ) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                .hidden()
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            )
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }

    func clearSelectedListing() {
        selectedListingId = nil
        showListingPreview = false
    }
}

struct ListingMapView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListingMapView(isChildView: .constant(true))
    }
}

The feedback I received from the user is that they were clicking around the different pins on the map and zooming in & out when this happened. Could this be a resource issue? The crash log is a bit cryptic to understand.

I have seen such things over time - highly dependant on iOS version and target: iOS simulator, or Mac, or iOS Hardware. so please show exact versions and targets. Also, please look if you have violet error messages, indicating using background where you shouldn't for example.
